# Prove: Let $X$ be the universe and $A, B \subseteq X$. If $A \cap Y = B \cap Y \forall Y \subseteq X$ then $A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question in the book is in the question title, to prove or provide a counterexample:

Let $X$ be the universe and $A, B \subseteq X$.
$$ \text{If } A \cap Y = B \cap Y \text{ for all } Y \subseteq X, \text{then } A = B$$.

My first thought for the proof is the following:

Let $Y = B$. Then $A \cap B = B \cap B = B$, which implies $B \subseteq A$ (using a previously proven theorem). Similarly, let $Y = A$ and in the same way we see that $A \subseteq B$. Taken together, this shows that $A = B$.

This was also how it was done in the official solution.

My question, though, is: for a "for all" proof as above, is it generally acceptable to "specialize" $Y$ to $B$, and then let $Y$ equal $A$? That is, since I have to prove set equality, and I choose to show that both are subsets of each other, does the fact that they are "different" sets $Y$ cause an issue?

Comment: $~X = \Bbb{R},~ Y = \{ ~y \in \Bbb{R} ~: 0 \leq y \leq 3~\}.$  Then, take $~A = \{ ~a \in \Bbb{R} ~: -1 \leq y \leq 3~\}, ~B = \{ ~b \in \Bbb{R} ~: -2 \leq y \leq 3~\}.$

Comment: @AndreasBlass How can the proof be valid, when (per my previous comment's counter example), the assertion is false?

Comment: Your title has two "if"s but only one "then", which leads to ambiguity. Specifically, deleting the first "if" and retaining the second, the statement is false (as shown by @user2661923's comment). But deleting the second "if" and retaining the first, the statement is true, and your proof works.

Comment: @user2661923 I had deleted that comment, and I'll now delete the other one, but see my newer comment about ambiguity in the title.

Comment: Sorry, I'd written it without the book in front of me. Fixed both the title and post body to reflect the exact wording.

Comment: Of course, if the hypothesis is that something holds for every $a$, then you are entitled to assert that it holds for any particular choice(s) of $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your argument; the requirement that it holds for all $Y$ allows you to create an equality for each $Y$. However, one can do this in a single step, by letting $Y=A\cup B$, since
$$A=A\cap (A\cup B)=B\cap (A\cup B)=B.$$

Comment: Or let $Y=X$, for that matter.

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose my confusion comes from choosing Y. i.e., my discomfort was in thinking that I only chose one particular Y, not an "arbitrary" or "general" subset Y. Even though I came up with it, it seemed to me to be more of an existence proof; i.e., for some choice of Y we can show that A = B